# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi i have this problem in xcode..

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
          _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
          _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      "_inflate", referenced from:
          _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

online i haven't found any solution, have any idea? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Apple [mailnglists](http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-dev/2005/Jan/msg01253.html):

To use the routines, include zlib.h in your source and libz.dylib into your project.

Or get zlib: [zlib.net](http://zlib.net/)

Or get the CocoaPod: [objective-zip](http://cocoapods.org/?q=zlib)

Comment: Your answer helped me with Google Maps iOS SDK.